# oracle and character encoding

Tags: sql, oracle, character-encoding, character

What is the highest and lowest character encoding? Below is the case scenario this is required.

I have a user form and user enters data for example last_name. They have option of leaving this field blank. When it is left blank, in the background following sql is running

```
select em_id from em
 where (last_name < user_entered_value)
   and (first_name > user_entered_value)
```

When user enters nothing, we get null comparisons. I can replace above with NVL, BUT I need to know the lowest and highest character encoding in order to get correct set of results. For example 'ZZZ' need to be replaced with highest character encoding and I don't know what that is.

```
select em_id from em 
 where (last_name < NVL(user_entered_value,'ZZZ'))
   and (first_name > NVL(user_entered_value,'A'))
```

Thanks in advance,
Bruce

Comment: Lowest is 'A' and Highest is 'Z' for only alphabets (Case Sensitive).. If you want to include all characters.. Find the the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) .. Lowest ASCII would be the lowest bound you look for.. And vice versa..

Comment: I tried that however 'Z' doesn't cover all character codes, for example greek character O is higher than 'Z'

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar 'Z' isn't necessarily the last letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use "is null" instead:

select em_id from em 
 where (last_name < user_entered_value or user_entered_value is null)
   and (first_name > user_entered_value or user_entered_value is null)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe LNNVL would be a better solution here:

```
select em_id from em
 where LNNVL(last_name >= user_entered_value)
   and LNNVL(first_name <= user_entered_value)
```